# Retrieve all the products attribute using rest api

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, rest-api

I am new to magento2 and learning using rest API of magento2.

I want all products to attribute that is present in the database. I searched in the database and I found that the table `eav_attribute` contains all attrs.

I would like to retrieve all these attributes using rest API.
I have tried the following endpoints:

```
rest/V1/products/attribute-sets//attributes
rest/V1/eav/attribute-sets/list?searchCriteria... field attribute_set_name
rest/V1/eav/attribute-sets/list?searchCriteria... field entity_entry_id
```

and more others but I am not able to find.

I have tried this too. `rest/V1/products/attribute-sets/9/attributes`
but I don't get all attributes. I.e the color attribute available in Magento admin but I can't get using rest api.

Please, can you help me?

Comment: are you working  with `Default` Attribute set ?

Comment: no, but I got what I wanted lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I wanted I achieved by this endpoint `/rest/V1/products/attributes`

and using this search Criteria

```
$params= ['searchCriteria' => 
               ['filterGroups' => 
                        [0 => [
                             'filters' => [ 
                                         0 => [ 
                                            'field' => 'attribute_id', 
                                            'value' => 1, 
                                            'condition_type' => 'gteq' 
]
        ]]]]];
```