# Get All attributes of a product By ID magento 2.3 REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am trying to create a custom API to get all attributes of a product.

```
{{host}}/products/attribute-sets/17/attributes
{{host}}/products/attributes?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=attribute_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=97, 75, 125, 87, 128, 78, 104, 101, 135, 73, 76, 88, 84, 79, 106, 102, 74, 89, 85, 80, 117, 100, 122, 157, 86, 81, 116, 77, 90, 92, 91, 121, 96, 119, 134, 120, 98, 115, 124, 158, 103, 159, 129, 160, 82, 161, 107, 123, 108, 162, 109, 99, 110, 105, 111, 94, 112, 95, 113, 163, 164, 114, 167, 165, 130, 131, 132, 133, 136&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=in&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=is_visible_on_front&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

What I want is a combined result of above mentioned API.When I call

```
{{host}}/products/attribute-sets/17/attributes
```

API, It doesn't provide all attributes value (like is_visible_on_front..).To get a detailed attribute I have to call the next API with all attribute id returned from the first API. So I wanted to know if there is a built-in API to achieve the result. Or how to create a custom API for the result. Please somebody help.

Comment: you refer this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249018/retrieve-all-the-products-attribute-using-rest-api

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Magento-2-use-REST-API-to-get-list-of-attribute-sets-for-Django/td-p/39350

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After refering to this answer 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/282395/87036

, I was able to produce the result I wanted.

```
public function getProductAttributes($id)
{

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
    $attributeSetId = $_product->getData('attribute_set_id');
    $groupCollection = $this->attributeGroupCollection->create()
        ->setAttributeSetFilter($attributeSetId)
        ->load(); 
    $attributeCollection = [];
    foreach ($groupCollection as $group) {
        $groupAttributesCollection = $this->productAttributeCollection->create()
            ->setAttributeGroupFilter($group->getId())
            ->addVisibleFilter()
            ->load(); 

        foreach ($groupAttributesCollection->getItems() as $attribute) {
                $attribute_code = $attribute->getData('attribute_code');

                $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attribute_code);
                $options['options'] = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

                $attributeCollection[] = array_merge($attribute->getData(), $options);
        }
    }

    return $attributeCollection;

}
```